Auto_increment doesn't change after alter table
We switched servers and hosting, and on the new server after writing:
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=some_number;

we see notification that it's changed and everything ok, but when we check it with:
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'

we see that auto_increment didn't change. Our DevOps says: "On the new version of MySQL you can't change auto_increment as you did before, now you need to dump restore". We have MySQL 8.0.39, Linux.
Is there a way to change it without dumping the whole table? And what reasons could cause this bug?

Our DevOps says: "On the new version of MySQL you can't change auto_increment as you did before, now you need to dump restore" Very strange statement... Reference Manual does not agree. But it tells that You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the value that is currently in use. For both InnoDB and MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one. I.e. your some_number must be not less than max value already present in AI column.

Does SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name give you the value you expect? Note that on MySQL 8.0, some statistics in information_schema are not updated except once every 24 hours by default. This is configurable, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry

Thank you for your answers. Akina - yes, I said that to him, that we don't want to lower AUTO_INCREMENT, but his answer was the same, I'm not Dev Ops, so my word against his has less value for Team Lead. But as I understand this is wrong, and I should have ability to increase AUTO_INCREMENT.

Bill Karwin - As I know, this will give me the value of the last row, but I need AUTO_INCREMENT, I wrote "ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=some_number;" and had the same value as I had before entering this command. Thank you for your answer and the link, I will read it, maybe it's indeed updating once a day.

Is some_number more than MAX(id) or not?  (It makes a difference.)

No, we have table with numbers till 750123 and I wanted to change it to 760432(not actual numbers, just example)
